# Get claims from custom STS token before sharepoint 2013 make spuser

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm trying get claim information from an STS token provided by our custom STS.

When our STS ceates a token, it provides an email address and a custom field named `registration number`.

Now I want to use the claim in SharePoint, I have no access to it because SharePoint makes a `SPUser` object from the claim and `SPUser` has no field named `registration number`.

How can I access this claim data in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helped me to solve the issue.
http://sharepintblog.com/2011/10/26/adding-additional-claims-to-a-trusted-identity-token-issuer/

Answer (score 0):

This is how we've done it in our sharepoint code

```
IClaimsPrincipal cp = HttpContext.Current.User as IClaimsPrincipal;
IClaimsIdentity = cp.Identity as IClaimsIdentity;
ClaimCollection claims = ci.Claims;
```

This is somewhat contrived for the sake of completeness. We've got extension methods helping us in our claims processing system.

You can find more details [at the IClaimsPrincipal MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.iclaimsprincipal.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and my apologies for late reply. I have used this code before but when I want to iterate over the claims I have access to the SAML token and his claims but I cannot find the specific claim. It may needs some modification on configuration file or somewhere else?

Comment: I have solved it by mapping the claims via PowerShell script in the SharePoint environment.